# how to fetch jquery serialization data in controller and store to db

Tags: jquery, laravel

i am sending multiple dynamic input boxes data using ajax so i don't know how to retrieve data in controller and save to database.

```
$(".btn_sb").click(function(){

                    var dt=$(".eq_form").serialize();
                    alert(dt);
                    $.ajax({
                        headers: {
                   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        url:'/add-ques',
                        type:'post',
                        data:{ques:dt},
                        success:function(data){

                            if(data.success){
                                //alert("done");
                                $(".scs_msg").fadeIn();
                                //$(".eq_form").trigger('reset');
                            }

                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                        console.log('Error:', data);
                         }


                    });
```

RESPONSE

```
 Array ( [ques] => _token=js1wz0cTOx7IX20qWuStea79BVgevypvHZReA47X&ques=q1&opta=a&optb=b&optc=c&optd=d&ques2=q2&opta2=a&optb2=b&optc2=c&optd2=d )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send them by using array.
You should have checkbox with certain data_id.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="{{$device->deviceid}}"></td>

// javascript to check and uncheck box
$('.checkbox').on('click', function () {
if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
    $('.checkbox').checked = false;
} else {
    $('.checkbox').checked = true;
}
});
var idsArr = [];
$(".checkbox:checked").each(function () {
    idsArr.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
});

$.ajax({
url: "{{ route('report.showreports') }}",
method: 'GET',
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
data: {
    ids: idsArr,
},
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    $('.container-fluid').html(data.html);
},
error: function (data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
}
});
```

Comment: it ok maybe it would help others. But this code is working for me that's why I suggest you

Comment: so can you please give me solution related to my code

Answer (score 0):

The data you're sending is unnecessarily nested in another object. The string format you're currently sending can be parsed by PHP using the native [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) function, then you can use a [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to iterate over each key-value pair in the resulting array.

You could also try using jQuery's `serializeArray()` function instead of `serialize()`, and then passing that result directly into the data like so:

```
var dt=$(".eq_form").serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    // ... 
    url:'/add-ques',
    type:'post',
    data: dt,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: i will parse it for now but when all the inputs are generated dynamically so that time how will i reterieve ?

Comment: You can use a `foreach` loop to iterate over each key-value pair in the resulting array. (updated answer with links to documentation)